# Smooth completion of algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, formal-completions

I am having trouble understanding the concept of smooth completions of algebraic curves. I know the definition (smooth, complete curves which contain the curve X as an open subset ) and according to Wikipedia they are even unique over perfect fields. But how can I construct a smooth completion of a given curve? Are they the same as projective closures?

Comment: Given a smooth (affine) algebraic curve embedded in some affine space, its projective closure can fail to be smooth. The correct procedure is described in §6 of [Hartshorne, Ch. I].

Comment: Could you maybe give a more intuitive explanation of the completion? Like what happens when the curve is given by a polynomial f(x,y) ?

Comment: Even in that case it can happen that the projective closure is not smooth.

Comment: so in order to construct the smooth completion you take the projective closure and then blow up the singularities?

Comment: Yes, that's one way of doing it. Blowups are birational and every birational equivalence class of projective algebraic curves contains a unique smooth algebraic curve.