# Affine vs projective from a higher standpoint

Tags: category-theory, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

While studying geometry, I came to know that a projective space (of dimension n associated to a vector space over a field K) can be seen as an affine space (of the same dimension and on the same field) extended with points at infinity. This extension perspective also pertains morphisms since, fixing an appropriate identification of the affine space into the projective one, affinities of the former can be viewed as special projectivities of the latter.

I am aware of the existence of category theory which can formalise similar interplays. Is there an interpretation of this case? More generally, I wonder to know (by willing scholars more advanced than me) if there exists an appropriate higher standpoint in which this relation can be interpreted.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to read [Erlangen Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program).

Comment: There is a differential geometry point of view : projective space can be considered as a differentiable manifold with an 'atlas' of affine maps. See [here](https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2017/Cameron1.pdf).

Comment: @MikhailKatz Thanks for your reply. I do know the principles inspiring the Erlangen program and I know there can be an interpretation of this case, I just feel it to be too generic to be enlightening. It basically points out that the same space may have different groups of (auto)morphisms leading to different invariants, while in the case I recalled above there are spaces (affine) which can be embedded (non-canonically) into other spaces and it's because of this expansion that automorphisms change. I am looking for a formalisation of this more specific circumstance.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for your reply. I must admit differential geometry is currently beyond my expertise. Anyway, can you provide a reference in which that idea is exposed or better spelled out? Or explain it yourself, if you please.

Comment: See the reference I just added to my comment.

Comment: @AmandaWealth, So you want something that says that there is a functor from the category of affine spaces to the category of projective spaces, transforming affine morphisms to projective morphisms in such a way that the transformation is injective?

Comment: @MikhailKatz I'd like an enlighting abstraction of the procedure of extension of an affine space to a projective one, not only set-theoretically speaking but also pertaining morphisms (i.e. categorically): a worthy generalisation. E.g., the existence of a functor could work in principle, but can it be informative about this precise situation?

Comment: What makes things fairly "categorical" is that one can remove *any* projective hyperplane from the projective space, with the result being an affine space $A$ (sometimes called an "affine neighborhood"), where the projective transformations preserving $A$ are precisely the affine transformations of $A$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I know this property, I think a good abstraction has to take into account also this.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Let me make a simple example to suggest what I am looking for. Saying (Z,+,0) (set of real integers with usual sum operation) is a group is undoubtedly true, but does not say much about it if you think of how different a group can be from it. On the other hand, if you say that (Z,+,0) is a cyclic infinite group, you chacterise it up to isomorphism and therefore catch the essence of the group-theoretic properties of it. Therefore saying "there exists a functor" may be true, but still sounds incomplete if I think of the generality of a functor.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the notion of *projective completion*.   To any algebraic variety one can associate its projective completion which will be a compact variety.  When one applies projective completion to an affine space, one gets a projective space.  When one applies it to a smooth affine complex-algebraic curve, one gets a compact Riemann surface.  This can be done algebraically via rings of functions.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Thank you for the suggestion. Could you provide a reference treating it?

Comment: A good starting point for the smooth projective completion is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_completion#Construction and the discussion in comments under https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702988/smooth-completion-of-algebraic-curves (unfortunately there is no formal answer, but Hartshorne is cited).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I think rather concretely of projective versus affine spaces.

You start with the category of vector spaces, where the morphisms are linear isomorphisms.

The projective space associated with a vector space $V$ is the set $\newcommand\P{\mathbb{P}}$$\P V$ of $1$-dimensional subspaces.  Projective transformations are maps naturally induced by linear isomorphisms. Any linear isomorphism $L: V \rightarrow W$ induces a map $$[L]: \P V \rightarrow \P W,$$ where for each $\ell \in \P V$, $$[L](\ell) = L(\ell).$$

To make this abstract, we can say that $\P$ is a projective space if there exists a vector space $V$ such that $\P = \P V$ and $F: \P \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is a projective transformation if $\P = \P V$, $\mathbb Q = \P W$, and there exists a linear isomorphism $L: V \rightarrow W$ such that $F = [L]$.

This defines a functor from the category of vector spaces to the cateogry of projective spaces, where all morphisms are bijective.

An affine space arises as an affine hyperplane of a vector space. In other words, $\newcommand\A{\mathbb{A}}$$\A$ is an affine space if there exists a vector space $V$ and nonzero $\xi \in V^*$ such that $$\A = \xi^{-1}(1). $$ There is a natural injective map \begin{align*} \A &\rightarrow \P V\\ v &\mapsto [v], \end{align*} where $[v]$ is the $1$-dimensional subspace containing $v$. A map $\A_1 \rightarrow \A_2$ is an affine trasnformation if it is the restriction of a projective transformation $$[L]: \P V_1 \rightarrow \P V_2.$$

The complement $\P V\backslash \A$ is called the hyperplane at infinity. Given the definition above of an affine space, there is a unique way to extend $\A$ to an isomorphism class of projective spaces. That's what is meant by projectivizing $\A$ by adding the hyperplane at infinity. Also, any affine transformation has a unique extension to a projective transformation.